# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED font awesome

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to use the social media icons from font awesome to add to my website. I downloaded and dragged the font awesome folder into my project. Then i copied

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

into the `<head>` of the html.

I researched that if I'm doing it locally I should add https://

So I did. (I've tried it without it and it still didn't work) Then i added

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in the jumbotron.

The icon didn't show up. I inspected the elements and got this error

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED https://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: No need to add `https://` if you are trying to refer relative path to your folder. just add relative path `<link href="/folder/file.css">`

Comment: Quick way to check would be to try that URL https://path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css in a browser, which fails.

Answer (score 1):

on your link to import css document make sure to add the attribute
type="text/css" that might solve it :)

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to put: path/to/  this is to tell you to put there your path!So check the name of folder you put your font-awesome in it and put the path , example : if you called your folder "fonts" your path should be:
fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css